# Javascript: How do I prevent my Fibonacci generator from producing two "1"?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let sayi3 = 0, sayi4 = 1, nextTerm;
let number = 10;

console.log("Girdiğiniz sayının sırasına kadar olan Fibonacci değerleri:");

for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    console.log(sayi3);
    nextTerm = sayi3 + sayi4;
    sayi3 = sayi4;
    sayi4 = nextTerm;
}
```

This is the output:

[image: output]

There is nothing wrong with my code, I just want to know how can I stop it from generating two 1's. Can you tell me the solution if possible?

I've searched forums and stackoverflow but no results

Comment: You can start the sequence at 1,2 : `let sayi3 = 1, sayi4 = 2`

Comment: But my team leader wants it to start at 0.

Comment: @EnginEmreDeniz Ask your team leader then: How can 0 + 1 not equal to 1?

Comment: @InSync Okay, i will.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence - it is correct to have two ones

Comment: If you want to start at `0` but don't want to produce two `1` values then what you want is not a Fibonacci sequence.  It's *very similar* to a Fibonacci sequence, but follows slightly modified rules.  So you'd have to write something other than a Fibonacci generator, something that includes your custom logic for your custom rules.

Comment: Tip: Never say 'There is nothing wrong with my code' in a stackoverflow thread. Coding is a craft in which we can always find better ways to implement our code. Tell your leader  you can't log 'Fibonacci values ​​up to the order of the number you entered'  without printing  two ones since Fibonnaci sequence includes 2 ones: 0,1,1,2,3,5,8 check wiki link above.

Comment: If your goal is to get all *unique* Fibonacci numbers (e.g. to generate reasonable values for an agile planning poker session) then you can put them into a collection of some kind (array, map, etc.) and only add to that collection if it doesn't already contain the value...

Comment: Using a Set: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y50jcums/

Comment: @mplungjan Using a `Set` to filter out a single duplicate value is a bit overkill. The next value can never be the same as its former two unless one of them is 0, which happens only once.

Comment: @InSync I know, but it was interesting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence):

`0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144 ...`

If you want only one `1`, that's not called `Fibonacci sequence` anymore, however, you can do it this way:

```js
let sayi3 = 1;
let sayi4 = 2;
let nextTerm;
let number = 10;
console.log(0)
for (let i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
    console.log(sayi3);
    nextTerm = sayi3 + sayi4;
    sayi3 = sayi4;
    sayi4 = nextTerm;
}
```

Comment: Oh, its in its nature to have two 1's then right? I thought I made a mistake there.

Comment: Yes, basically Fibonacci is saying that the first number is `0` and the second number is `1` and after that, every number is the sum of two previous numbers. It means the third is going to be `0+1` which is `1`. the fourth is `1+1` which is `2` and so on.